# Webpage create / edit file

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html

I'm working on a webpage that has to work offline when it's finished. No XAMPP or other services available, so PHP is no option.
It has to create a new file, edit a filename (which would be the best solution) or move a file into another directory. This action has to be called from a function in jQuery.
I've read that Python could to this but as long as I read Python needs a web framework and a configured Apache as well, so if it's right Python is no possibility for me as well.
Is there any way to do this with JavaScript / jQuery or anything else which works offline?

Comment: Take a look at the following:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13405129/javascript-create-and-save-file

Answer (score 0):

No. It won't work by Design. Imagine, you visit a Website and it would install virus.exe into your Windows Directory (For example Autostart).

Html Pages are for Displaying Informationen to the User. Javascript is supporting it with dynamic Features. The Browser grant Rights for Loading other Information and nothing else. Everything which would affect the System, could not handled by Script.

If it should run from Web, you need a Plugin (Like Java). In your case (Offline Use) consider to write a Desktop Client (C#, VB.NET, Java, C++).